# how to config htaccess file after enabling mod_rewrite module in ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, ubuntu, mod-rewrite

I already install `apache2` then i enable the `mod_rewrite` module like this:

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
```

after enabling i am confused about these lines, i can't understand what to do with them, as far as i know that what i have to do with these lines is that **" find the following section, and change the line that says AllowOverride from None to All. "**

```
<Directory /var/www/>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride All
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
</Directory>
```

my problem is that I can't find a file with the above lines to edit.
I already looked in `/etc/apache2/sites-available/`. In that directory, I only found two files:

```
000-default.conf 
default-ssl.conf
```

In both files i can't find above lines which i have to edit.

i edit the file  `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` in this directory but it still didn't worked at all.

i am working in `/var/www/html/project_name` directory then why it's giving me 403 forbidden error.

when i open info.php in this `/var/www/html/info.php` it show php information and works fine. whenever i switch to my project directory it's gives me 403 forbidden error

Still `.htaccess` is not running. It's giving me 403 forbidden error.

Comment: did you have a `/etc/apache2/conf/` folder? or `/etc/httpd/`?

Comment: i have `/etc/apache2/` inside of `apache2` contains these folders: `conf-available`, `con-enabled`, `mods-available`, `mods-enabled`, `sites-available`, `sites-enabled` and it contains files these are: `apache2.conf` i think other three are not important